# Campo calculado

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, phpmyadmin

Boa tarde,

Eu tenho uma base de dados feita com recurso à ferramenta phpMyAdmin, mas com base em SQL.

A base de dados tem um tabela que tem um campo calculado. A tabela tem 6 registos, mas, quando eu faço o comando para o campo calculado, esse comando não aplica em todos os registos.

Eu já fiz um "Trigger", no phpMyAdmin, para fazer update à tabela depois de inserir um registo, mas não resulta.

Conseguem ajudar-me?

Obrigado

Comment: Coloca a estrutura da tabela na sua pergunta.

Comment: @RodolphoSa Muito obrigado, mas já não é preciso. Já consegui